# How can I sort this using pivot as the leftmost key?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

How can I sort this using pivot as the leftmost key in quick sort? I'm getting the answer incorrectly.

```
public class QuicksortApp {
    private static int []a = {10, 12, 9, 23, 45, 31, 67, 44, 32, 77};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int left = 0;
        int right = a.length - 1;       

        // prints the given array
        printArray();

        quickSort(left, right);

        System.out.println("");

        //prints the sorted array
        printArray();

    }

    private static void quickSort(int left, int right) {

        // If both cursor scanned the complete array quicksort exits
        if(left >= right)
            return;

        // We took the right most item of the array as a pivot 
        int pivot = a[right];
        int partition = partition(left, right, pivot);

        quickSort(0, partition - 1);
        quickSort(partition + 1, right);
    }

    private static int partition(int left, int right, int pivot) {
        int leftCursor = left - 1;
        int rightCursor = right;

        while(leftCursor < rightCursor){
                while(a[++leftCursor] < pivot);
                while(rightCursor > 0 && a[--rightCursor] > pivot);
            if(leftCursor >= rightCursor) {
                break;
            } else {
                swap(leftCursor, rightCursor);
            }
        }
        swap(leftCursor, right);
        return leftCursor;
    }

    public static void swap(int left, int right) {
        int temp = a[left];
        a[left] = a[right];
        a[right] = temp;
    }

    public static void printArray() {
        for(int i : a){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your pivot be `pivot=a[left]` if you want the left most key as your pivot?

Comment: I put that so....but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class QuicksortApp {
private static int[] a = { 10, 12, 9, 23, 45, 31, 67, 44, 32, 77 };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int left = 0;
    // you do not need to pass the length -1 because the for loop takse care
    // of it.
    int right = a.length;

    // prints the given array
    printArray();

    quickSort(left, right);

    System.out.println("");

    // prints the sorted array
    printArray();

}

private static void quickSort(int left, int right) {

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    //no need to pass the pivot since the pivot will always be the left most element in the array
    int partition = partition(left, right);

    quickSort(0, partition - 1);
    quickSort(partition + 1, right);
}

private static int partition(int left, int right) {

    int pivot = a[left];

    int splitter = left;
    /*
     * This is cleanest approach to the algorithm. I am not going to mention
     * the pseudo code of the alog but since you were trying to modify the
     * array in place,you need to decide what will be your separation
     * point,In my case this is called "splitter". The splitter takes care
     * of creating a boundary between the elements greater than and lesser
     * than the pivot
     */
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
        // Check if the element currently being scanned is less than the
        // pivot
        if (pivot > a[i]) {
            // If it is lesser,then left most element which is greater than
            // the pivot with this element and increase your boundary
            // pointer(splitter) by one
            swap(++splitter, i);
        }
        // Do not do anything if the element is lesser than the pivot.

    }
    // swap the pivot and element at the splitter position
    // Please note that the splitter position contains the right most
    // element with a value lesser than the pivot
    swap(left, splitter);
    // return the splitter,which indicates the position of your pivot and
    // provides you information regarding how you should split and partition
    // to implement the Divide and Conquer Paradigm
    return splitter;
}

public static void swap(int left, int right) {
    int temp = a[left];
    a[left] = a[right];
    a[right] = temp;
}

public static void printArray() {
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
}
```

I have tried explaining with as many comments as possible.I presume this is some sort of assignment,So please try to understand the logic because the algorithms only get more complex as they come.This is one of the most simple algorithms.